# --abort-on-container-exit is not working after exited the terminal

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use `docker-compose up --build --abort-on-container-exit` to start the application, `--abort-on-container-exit` works while I'm hanging and monitoring the log(do nothing after running the command), however, it failed after I exited the terminal, and check the logs using `docker-compose logs`, only the error container exit, other containers keep running.

Example:

My project structure:

- first-test.js
- second-test.js
- docker-compose.yml
- first-test.Dockerfile
- second-test.Dockerfile
- package.json

first-test.js:

```js
async function foo1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    if (i === 20) {
      throw "Error";
    }
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}
}

foo1();
```

second-test.js

```js
async function foo2() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
}

foo2();
```

first-test.Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:21
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
CMD [ "node", "first-test.js" ]
```

second-test.Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:21
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
CMD [ "node", "second-test.js" ]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  first-test:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./first-test.Dockerfile

  second-test:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./second-test.Dockerfile
```

Both containers aborted after `first-test.js` threw the error if I just started the application by `docker-compose up --build --abort-on-container-exit`. However, if I closed the terminal before the error was thrown and checked the container logs by `docker-compose logs`, I see the `second-test.js` keep running and `first-test.js` is not. Why `second-test.js` is running even I added `abort-on-container-exit` in the `docker-compose up` command?

Comment: If you close the terminal in which you were running `docker-compose`, then `docker-compose` is no longer running and is no longer monitoring the state of your compose stack.

Comment: How can I monitor the state of the compose stack in this case? Cause when I run `docker-compose up` inside the vm through the ssh connection, after the connection is lost due to my local network issue and I ssh back to the vm, the same situation as the question mentioned happens. @larsks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker doesn't have any native mechanism to monitor a set of containers started with `docker compose` (or `docker-compose`). Effectively, `docker compose` is just a fancy wrapper around `docker run`; it doesn't let you do anything that you couldn't reproduce with a bunch of individual `docker run` invocations.

You *can* set a restart policy on individual containers so that they will restart automatically if they fail. That would look like  this:

```
services:
  first-test:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./first-test.Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure

  second-test:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./second-test.Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
```

That will cause individual containers to restart in the event of a failure.

If you need containers to restart as the result of failures in *another* container, you would need to implement code that causes your application to handle that situation.

Comment: Thank you, a bit off-topic, but may I ask how would you implement the same effect as `--abort-on-container-exit` (stop all containers/scripts once one of them fails) as `docker-compose` did?

Comment: I think the answer to that really depends on your specific situation. For example, you could implement logic in your application(s) so that they exit if a dependent service becomes unavailable, causing the container to restart. Alternately, you could implement some sort of monitoring service that watches the docker api for container failures and then triggers a restart.